# Einstein Content Selection | Sync Your Consumer Profile Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, einstein

I followed Einstein Content Selection documentation provided by SFMC to understand the feature better. I created and uploaded asset catalog file.

Next I want to use customer profile attributes using a sendable Data Extension that I created in Contact Builder. As per https://help.salesforce.com/articleViewid=mc_pb_sync_your_consumer_profile_data_extension.htm&type=5 , when I navigate to Settings tab and click on 'Sync Data Extension' button, a pop up appears from where I should be able to select my sendable DE, but I don't see any DE in the list.
[image]

Has someone worked on this and faced similar issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to enter a name in the search?

Comment: Yes, tried to enter the complete name, partial name. And there are many sendable DEs that exist in that business unit, not one DE is visible here.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't have this issue, are the DE in the shared folder?

Comment: No the DE is not in the shared folder. The Einstein Content Selection functionality is enabled only for 1 Business unit(child BU) in my account. I created the DE in that particular BU only.

Comment: I would suggest opening a support case to assist

Comment: Yes, did that already. Will update if I get any useful insights from support team. Thanks!